# Three line equations form a triangle. How do I find the equations for the heights?

Tags: triangles, analytic-geometry

The line equations:
$$x+2y-1=0$$
$$5x+4y-17=0$$
$$x-4y+11=0$$
form a triangle,

How can I find the line equations for the heights of that triangle, without searching for the coordinates of the vertices?
I know it has to do with the intersection of the lines, but I don't know how to find the symmetrical line of that angle.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, find where each pair intersects, then take the difference of the largest $y$ value and the smallest $y$ value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> without searching for the coordinates of the vertices?

There isn't any need to "search" for the coordinates of the vertices, because the coordinates of a vertex are nothing but the solution of the equations of the two lines that intersect to form that vertex. I will therefore solve the three equations to get the vertex coordinates since I have been provided with them.

Suppose the vertices are $A, B$ and $C$, and the equations correspond to lines $AB, BC$ and $AC$. Thus we have three equations for three lines:
$$AB: x + 2y - 1 = 0$$
$$BC: 5x + 4y -17 = 0$$
$$AC: x - 4y + 11 = 0$$

By solving the equations for AB & AC, AB & BC, and BC & AC respectively, we get the following coordinates: $A(5, -2)$, $B(1, 3)$, $C(-3, 2)$. Also, by expressing the equations in [slope-intercept form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_equation#Slope%E2%80%93intercept_form), we get $m_{AB} = \frac{-1}2$, $m_{BC} = \frac{-5}4$ and $m_{AC} = \frac{1}4$.

Again suppose, the three heights are $AD, BE$ and $CF$. That means, line $AD$ is perpendicular to $BC$, $BE$ is perpendicular to $AC$ and $CF$ is perpendicular to $AB$. We now recall that the slope of a perpendicular line is the **negative inverse** of the slope of the base (the proof is fairly easy so I will leave that out). Using this knowledge, we get the following slopes: $m_{AD} = -\frac{1}{m_{BC}} = \frac{4}5$, $m_{BE} = -\frac{1}{m_{AC}} = -4$ and $m_{CF} = -\frac{1}{m_{AB}} = 2$.

Since we have the coordinates of the vertices and the slopes of the perpendiculars from the vertices (which are of course lines passing through the vertices), we can easily construct equations for the three perpendiculars using $m = \frac{y-y_1}{x-x_1}$ which we get from the definition of slope. Therefore, the three required equations for three perpendiculars are:
$$AD: 4x - 5y + 30 = 0$$
$$BE: -4x - y + 7 = 0$$
$$CF: 2x - y + 8 = 0$$

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can find one coordinate for one vertice (lets say where the first two lines intersect) and then find the equation of the line perpendicular to $x-4y+11=0$ that passes through the point you just calculated.